# How to automate pagination using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, pagination, web-crawler

I wanted to extract data from multiple pages of a website. I was successfully able to extract the data from the first page, but was unable to move to the next page by using the next button...I will really appreciate if you would advise me in pagination. I am mentioning some part of the code where the suggestion is required...

```
def check_element_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True
count = 0
while check_element_exists_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'next')]"):
    try:
        if count > 0:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'next')]")
        mailcollector()
        count = count + 1
    except(NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException, WebDriverException):
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.refresh()
        driver.back()
```

The Inspect element HTML code for **Next** button is

```
<li class = "pagination-link next-link">
<a data-aa-region="srp-pagination" data-aa-name="srp-next-page"
<span>next</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Can you give more information? Giving the link of the website, describing what happens when you click the button (for example is there an error? or is there any timing problems?), and any other information that can help to understand your problem better. :)

Comment: I was not able to click the next button after extracting data from the first page. Any website where next button is available.

Comment: What exception are you facing while clicking on Next button ?

Comment: I am not getting any exception; however, I am unable to click the next button to move to another page.